# Example of a discrete uniform subgroup of a Lie group which is not virtually torsion-free

Tags: lie-groups, examples-counterexamples, lattices-in-lie-groups

I'm looking for an example, or source of examples, of a discrete uniform subgroup $G$ of a Lie group $\Gamma$, with $G$ *not* virtually torsion-free.  By uniform subgroup I mean that the quotient $\Gamma / G$ is compact.

The furthest I have been able to get with this is that it cannot be done for simply connected soluble Lie groups - any uniform subgroup is a lattice (the quotient $\Gamma / G$ has finite volume in the Haar measure), and such lattices have matrix representations.  Selberg's Lemma provides that $G$ is virtually torsion-free.  (The Lemma states that a finitely generated linear group over a field of zero characteristic is virtually torsion-free.)

Any suggested references / reading would also be much appreciated, I don't know this area particularly well, so I don't really know where to look for these things.

Comment: [This question on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73456/uniform-lattices-in-semisimple-lie-groups) contains some useful information. // A remark on notation: it is customary to write $G$ for the Lie group and $\Gamma$ for the lattice, not the other way around.

Comment: @Martin Thanks, this solves my question, the comment by Misha on that MathOverflow question references "Torsion in cocompact lattices in coverings of spin (2,n) - M. S. Raghunathan" where an example of a cocompact lattice which is not virtually torsion-free is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MathOverflow question on [Uniform lattices in semisimple Lie groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73456/) contains useful information and links.

In particular, Misha Kapovich posted a comment pointing to M. S. Raghunathan, *[Torsion in cocompact lattices in coverings of $\operatorname{Spin}(2,n)$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01458536)*, Mathematische Annalen, 266 (4). pp. 403-419, where examples are constructed.